# using grunt in launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

I loaded the yeoman generator-meanjs and opened it with Visual Studio Code.
The debugger works nicely.  When I clicked on the debug side bar button a
launch.json file was generated for me. The launch.json generator is looking at the package.json which has `"scripts": { "start": "grunt"}`.

The generator uses grunt to launch the application. The launch.json file had
the following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "grunt",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": ".",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

When I replace `'program' : 'grunt'` with server.js it works.  If I could change the type to grunt, but it seems only node or mono is supported there.

Comment: Try specifying an absolute path to `grunt` in `program`, for example `"C:\\Users\\magister\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\grunt-cli\\bin\\grunt"`, and check that the `cwd` makes sense (it should be a directory containing `Gruntfile.js`).

Comment: yes that worked.  The gruntfile runs. grabs dev env settings, sass, jshint,mkdir:upload, etc. however there is some port that it then cannot connect to.  I have check all other instances of the app are not running, the port changes on each attempt at startup.                                         Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::16406
        at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11),at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20),at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1238:14), and so on

Comment: "${env.APPDATA}\\npm\\node_modules\\grunt-cli\\bin\\grunt" is a way to avoid your username getting checked in.

Answer (score 10):

I managed to make it work by using an absolute path to grunt-cli, as follows:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Grunt",
            "args": ["build"],            
            "program": "${env.APPDATA}\\npm\\node_modules\\grunt-cli\\bin\\grunt", 
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

As pointed by @L.Butz, on newer vscode versions, replace `env.APPDATA` by `env:APPDATA`.

Comment: I noticed that my local version of VS Code (V 1.13.1, Windows) complains about the "env.APPDATA" and expects "env:APPDATA" instead. So changing the . to : was enough on my PC to make this work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @darksoulsong that helped me set my launch.json